# Firebase onauthstatechanged firing inconsistently on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I'm currently building a web app using react 17, react-router-dom v6 and firebase v9.

Specifically, on my iPhone SE (using both safari and chrome) when loading the page, I sometimes get stuck in a loading state because the app cannot determine wether the user is logged in or not.

Upon further debugging I've come to the realization that onAuthStateChanged is not always fired upon loading the page if I was previously logged in. I can circumvent this behaviour by manually refreshing the browser which forces onAuthStateChanged to fire again, which signs me back right in.

It is to my understanding that onAuthStateChanged should be fired at least once upon loading the page in order to determine if the user is authenticated or not.

This behaviour is especially common I manually type in the /login path in the URL bar while logged in..

I've wrapped my routes in an AuthProvider as shown in the [react-router auth example](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth). I'm also using guards to prevent the user from navigating to "/login" when authenticated and to "/" while not authenticated.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**AuthProvider.js**

```
export function AuthProvider({children}) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [isInitialized, setisInitialized] = useState(false);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setIsInitialized(true);
      },
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
  };

  if (isInitialized === false) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={
              <RequireLoggedOut>
                <Login />
              </RequireLoggedOut>
            }
          />

          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <RequireAuth>
                <Dashboard />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          />
          
          <Route
            path="/phone"
            element={
              <RequireLoggedOut>
                <LoginPhone />
              </RequireLoggedOut>
            }
          />

          <Route
            path="/profile"
            element={
              <RequireAuth>
                <Profile />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**RequireAuth.js**

```
export default function RequireAuth({children}) {
  const {currentUser} = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{from: location}} />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

**RequireLoggedOut.js**

```
export default function RequireLoggedOut({children}) {
  const {currentUser} = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();

  if (currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to="/" state={{from: location}} />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

### Update 1 2021-11-26

I added the pathname as a dependency as suggested by Noah Gwynn, as well as some log outputs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Mounting AuthContext');
    return () => {
      console.log('Cleaning authcontext');
    };
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('AuthContext path: ' + pathname);
    console.log('Attaching onAuthStateChanged');
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log('auth state changed');
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setisInitialized(true);
    });

    return () => {
      console.log('Detaching onAuth..');
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [pathname]);
```

Upon trying to load the /login path by manually typing in the URL bar I get this output roughly 20% of the time.

```
LOG: Mounting AuthContext
LOG: AuthContext path: /login
LOG: Attaching onAuthStateChanged
```

And this output, which CORRECTLY fires the observer the rest of the time.

```
LOG: Mounting AuthContext
LOG: AuthContext path: /login
LOG: Attaching onAuthStateChanged
LOG: auth state changed
LOG: Detaching onAuth..
LOG: AuthContext path: /
LOG: Attaching onAuthStateChanged
LOG: auth state changed
```

### Update 2 2021-11-26

Furthermore, if I hook up my iPhone to the Safari debug tool on MacOS the problem disappears and onAuthStateChanged is called properly everytime. As soon as I disable debugging the behaviour returns and onAuthStateChanged is not always called unless I refresh the page..

Comment: I know there were some issues on Safari recently, like [this one](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5644). What exact version of the Firebase Auth SDK are you using?

Comment: I am currently running Firebase 9.5.0. I am, however, also experiencing the issue on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the useEffect gets called on every time the page changes, then you could get the path value and pass it into the useEffect as a dependency.

Get the current path:

```
let pathname = useLocation().pathname
```

Put pathname into your useEffect dependancy array:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => {
        
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setIsInitialized(true);
      },
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [pathname]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried your solution but it is still not firing consistently. I added a few console logs in order to see how the change would affect things. I've updated my post with console.log additions and the console output.